# DateTime.ParseExact throwing format exception

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a date in the following format "hh:mm:ss:ffff dd/MM/yy" (for example..."20:58:54:5854 28/07/07") but when I try to parse that with DateTime.ParseExact it fails with a format exception.

My exact line of code is...

```
var time = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "hh:mm:ss:ffff dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Thanks
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `HH` instead of `hh` for 24 hour format time:

```
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, "HH:mm:ss:ffff dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```